# How to avoid bar charts in R shiny to affect each others height?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have a simple R shiny App where the user is supposed to select Species always as x axis and then select multiple column (not in the same time) as y axis.After that the user clicks on Plot Button to get the correspondent Bar chart .Then the user select another column and plot the next bar chart.First of all my app is labeling the y axis thing that i do not want.Second and this is the most important the subsequent bar chart is affecting the scaling of the previous one and this is my biggest problem .I forget to tell you that after selecting the species as column for the x axis and another column for y axis ,the use has to select rows since this one of most important Features of my app.I recommend here for testing my App to select the first 6 rows of the first page (setosa) and the first 7 lines (virginica) of the last page of the displayed data set and then click plot Button.Fell free to use ggplot2 instead of plotly and so on.Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Bar Chart"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("x_var"),
      uiOutput("y_var"),
      actionButton("plot_btn", "Plot")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data Table", DTOutput("data_table")),
        tabPanel("Bar Chart", plotlyOutput("bar_chart"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveVal(iris)
  selected_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  selected_y_columns <- reactiveVal(character(0))  # Record of selected y-axis columns
  colors <- reactiveVal(c("blue", "red", "green", "orange", "purple"))  # Color palette
  
  # Display dataset in an interactive table
  output$data_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(data(), editable = TRUE, selection = 'multiple')
  })
  
  # Select variables for X and Y axes
  output$x_var <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(data())) {
      selectInput("x_axis", "X Axis", choices = colnames(data()))
    }
  })
  
  output$y_var <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(data())) {
      selectInput("y_axis", "Y Axis", choices = colnames(data()))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_btn, {
    req(input$x_axis, input$y_axis)
    
    selected_rows <- input$data_table_rows_selected
    
    if (!is.null(selected_rows) && length(selected_rows) > 0) {
      selected_y_column <- input$y_axis
      
      # Check if the column has been previously selected
      if (selected_y_column %in% selected_y_columns()) {
        return(NULL)  # Exit observer function
      } else {
        selected_y_columns(c(selected_y_columns(), selected_y_column))  # Add to selected columns
        
        selected_data_list <- lapply(selected_rows, function(row) {
          x_data <- data()[row, input$x_axis]
          y_data <- data()[row, input$y_axis]
          data.frame(x = x_data, y = y_data)
        })
        
        selected_data_df <- do.call(rbind, selected_data_list)
        
        # Add selected data as a new plot
        if (is.null(selected_data())) {
          selected_data(list(selected_data_df))
        } else {
          selected_data(c(selected_data(), list(selected_data_df)))
        }
      }
    } else {
      # Handle case where no rows are selected
      print("No rows selected")
    }
  })
  
  # Create a dynamic bar chart
  # Create a dynamic bar chart
  output$bar_chart <- renderPlotly({
    if (!is.null(selected_data())) {
      p <- plot_ly()
      
      for (i in seq_along(selected_data())) {
        df <- selected_data()[[i]]
        color <- colors()[i]  # Get color from color palette
        
        # Calculate the x-axis position for this set of bars
        x_pos <- seq_along(df$x)
        
        # Check if x-axis column is categorical (character)
        if (is.character(df[[1]])) {
          p <- add_trace(p, data = df, x = ~as.factor(df[[1]]), y = ~df$y,
                         type = 'bar', name = colnames(df)[2], marker = list(color = color),
                         x = ~x_pos)
        } else {
          p <- add_trace(p, data = df, x = ~df[[1]], y = ~df$y,
                         type = 'bar', name = colnames(df)[2], marker = list(color = color),
                         x = ~x_pos)
        }
      }
      
      p <- layout(p, title = "Dynamic Bar Chart")
      p
    }
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I gave the code of my app and i am expecting to get a solution for my bar charts scaling troubles